# Iterating through a list to detect prime numbers

Tags: haskell, primes

i was given a homework in Haskell in which i should program a module, which helps detect prime numbers from a list, say :

```
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

For the homework, I should iterate through every elements of this list, and eliminate all of it's multiples. Example, I go at number 2, I should eliminate 4,6,8,10. Then go to number 3 and delete 6 and 9, and so on until the end, return the list with prime numbers only.

I have an idea of using function `map`, but I'm stuck at this place (I'm pretty new to Haskell, though)

Yes, it is my homework, but no, i don't *have* to do it, it's just practicing. So I'm thankful for any help.

Comment: What you describe is basically the [*Sieve of Eratosthenes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: yeah i know, i could do it with java but still having problems in haskell :)

Comment: Also note that there is i a full page at the haskell wiki dedicated to that problem - https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers there is a lot you can learn from reading now and re-reading it with more knowledge/experience

Comment: what you describe is `primes = map head . takeWhile (not . null) $ scanl (\\) [2..10] [[p, p+p..] | p <- primes] where (\\) = Data.List.Ordered.minus` (adapted from [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Prime_numbers#Definition)). but also `nubBy (((> 1) .) . gcd) [2..10]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a `map` (I don't think that's possible without doing some pre-processing), you can roll your own function:

```
sieveWith _  [] = []
sieveWith ss (x:xs) | any ((==) 0 . mod x) ss = sieveWith ss xs
                    | otherwise = x : (sieveWith (x:ss) xs)
```

and:

```
sieve = sieveWith []
```

Now if you call `sieve`:

```
*Main> sieve [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
[2,3,5,7]
```

The function works with a variable (the first one) that is passed through the function calls and each time a value is *picked*, added to the list. A value is picked if *no* modulo operation on the variable list yields a zero (second guard). In case [`any`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:any) of the [`mod`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:mod)ulo's yields zero, the value is simply omitted.

Comment: Many thanks ! i will have to study your answers, though, because some are really new for me. Theoretically i don't know about "otherwise", "any" and guards yet, but i guess this is some kind of excercise that requires some digging. Thanks again !

Comment: `otherwise` is basically an alias for `True` (but is more popular for guards). [`any`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:any) iterates through a list until it finds an element that satisfies a given condition.